# How to get error reason for bulk requests with failed records, via API

Tags: api, error, error-messages, bulk-api

After a Bulk API upsert, I can inspect the batch after the fact and see that my 4 records failed.

```
{
'apexProcessingTime': '0',
'apiActiveProcessingTime': '1',
'createdDate': '2017-07-21T15:33:47.000Z',
'id': '...',
'jobId': '...',
'numberRecordsFailed': '4',    # This is non-zero, so something went wrong
'numberRecordsProcessed': '4',
'state': 'Completed',
'systemModstamp': '2017-07-21T15:33:47.000Z',
'totalProcessingTime': '21',
}
```

Is there any way to get the *reason* they failed? An error message of any sort, so that I may correct whatever is wrong.

(For the curious, I'm using the [salesforce-bulk](https://github.com/heroku/salesforce-bulk) Python library, and used the `batch_status` function to get the above print out.)

Comment: Did you goto the bulk jobs ui in SF and download the error log. I believe the info is there. I am pretty sure you can get this via API as well but do not know syntax of the top of my head

Comment: Found the result.csv in the Salesforce dashboard (Setup -> Environments -> Jobs -> Bulk Data Load Jobs, or just searching "Bulk Data Load Jobs in the left-side search bar on Setup page"). Thanks! Separately, also wondering how to do with API, will edit the Q

Answer (score 2):

Using the [salesforce-bulk](https://github.com/heroku/salesforce-bulk) Python library I mentioned, see [this file](https://github.com/heroku/salesforce-bulk/blob/master/salesforce_bulk/salesforce_bulk.py) and find `def get_batch_results`.

If you're not in Python (which is quite likely), see how that function is defined. It uses a URI of the form:

`endpoint + "/job/<job_id>/batch/<batch_id>/result"`

where `endpoint` is the base Salesforce API URL you've been using. And insert your `job_id` and `batch_id` you get as direct response of the bulk request you want to observe the results for.

Note that they have handling for different response content types:

```
if resp.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/json':
    ...
elif resp.headers['Content-Type'] == 'text/csv':
    ...
elif resp.headers['Content-Type'] == 'application/xml':
    ....
```